# Can't pinpoint the exact nonetype error in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I've been doing a rather basic project in my fundamentals of software development class (I'll apologize in advance for my code), it's basically making a snakes and ladders which generates random snakes and ladders.

The error starts at around line 66, with the specific error being:
if FirstPlayerPosition > 99:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Here's [my github](https://gist.github.com/IamSketch/d4149c073c0460699932bb21cbf20c21) link to it, anyone can lend a hand?

Comment: maybe put your code here so people can see it and respond more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def CheckForSnake(t):
    if t in SnakePositions:
        t -= 10
        print("Oops! You've been bitten, go down 10 cells. Your new position is: %s" %(t))
        return t
    else:
        return t
```

`CheckForSnake` function had a chance to not return if `t` isn't in `SnakePositions` same goes for the `CheckForLadder` function. You'll need to return something for when the if statement won't get called.

Comment: That makes sense, but do you mind elaborating on what should be changed if you don't mind? How should I close off those two functions?

Comment: @YvanAlpay Yep! So this is more an issue with teaching a language like this over something like Java because the compiler will tell you that you're missing something.
In this case, you aren't handling the case where `t` isn't in `SnakePositions` so say `SnakePositions` is an array of `[5, 8, 9]` but `t` is 10, the if statement won't run because you're checking if the array contains 10 which it doesn't and thus won't return anything. I updated the answer with a working change.

Comment: Holy crap, thank you so much! Your explanation was excellent, it made sense as to why it happened!

Comment: @YvanAlpay glad I could help, welcome to StackOverflow btw. Be sure to mark your question as answered